# Mercurial: best way to push ignored file

Tags: version-control, mercurial

Sometimes need arises to update a library or file that has previously been put into .hgignore.
Normally, I would delete its entry from ignore list, commit/push a change and put ignore entry back.
Is this a good practice or there is some better/elegant way to deal with such a situation in Mercurial?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the `hgignore` man page

> The Mercurial system uses a file called .hgignore in the root directory of a repository to control its behavior when it searches for files that it is not currently tracking.

This library is obviously tracked. At some point you did `hg add <library>`. `hgignore` is no longer part of the equation for this file. In the future just update your library and commit.

`hgignore` is used for things like stopping mercurial talking about certain files when you do an `hg status` or adding them on `hg addremove`. It doesn't stop mercurial noticing if a tracked file changes.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to remove the entry from .hgignore; you can just `hg add` the file.

However, when you use a GUI, this GUI might use the .hgignore entries to show you a filtered list of files you can add. In this case, you would either have to add the file maqnually with `hg add`, or remove the entry temporarily from the .hgignore file.